# WebGL Basics: Using Render Loops to Apply 2D Convolution Filters to Buffer Canvases

Tags: javascript, image-processing, canvas, glsl, webgl

Very new to WebGL and attempting to port some 2D image processing shaders in order to get a handle on things. I initially was misled by the MDN tutorials into thinking WebGL was like OpenGL desktop, but then found [these tutorials](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-image-processing.html), which I found much more true to form as well as my purposes. However, I'm still having some trouble in formatting a render loop so I can pass a continually updating texture for processing. In cases where it does render, I just get a muddy mess and in cases where the vertex shader isn't a simple pass through I get nothing. I understand GLSL and the basics of how buffers work, but clearly am doing something very wrong here... Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```js
class GL {
    constructor(canvas){
        this.gl = canvas.getContext("webgl") || canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
        if (!this.gl) {
            alert("Unable to initialize WebGL. Your browser may not support it.");
            this.gl = null;
        }
 
        //init shaders
        var fragmentShader = getShader(this.gl, "fshader");
        var vertexShader = getShader(this.gl, "vshader");
        var shaderProgram = this.gl.createProgram();
        this.gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
        this.gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
        this.gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);
        this.gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);
        
        this.positionLocation = this.gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "position");
        this.texCoordLocation = this.gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "texcoord");
        var resolutionLocation = this.gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "resolution");
        this.width = this.gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "width");
    
        //set resolution
        this.gl.uniform2f(resolutionLocation, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        
        function getShader(gl, id) {
            var shaderScript, theSource, currentChild, shader;
            shaderScript = document.getElementById(id);

            if (!shaderScript) {
                return null;
            }

            theSource = "";
            currentChild = shaderScript.firstChild;
            
            while(currentChild) {
                if (currentChild.nodeType == currentChild.TEXT_NODE) {
                    theSource += currentChild.textContent;
                }
                currentChild = currentChild.nextSibling;
            }

            if (shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-fragment") {
                shader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
            } else if (shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-vertex") {
                shader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
            } else {
                // Unknown shader type
                return null;
            }

            gl.shaderSource(shader, theSource);
            gl.compileShader(shader);

            if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
                alert("An error occurred compiling the shaders: " + gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
                return null;
            }

                return shader;
        };
    };
    
    render(bufferCanvas, x, y) { 
        this.gl.clear(this.gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        //texture coordinates
        var texCoordBuffer = this.gl.createBuffer();
        this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.texCoordBuffer);
        this.gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this.texCoordLocation);
        this.gl.vertexAttribPointer(this.texCoordLocation, 2, this.gl.FLOAT, false, 8, 0);
        
        this.gl.bufferData(
            this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 
            new Float32Array([
                0.0,  0.0,
                1.0,  0.0,
                0.0,  1.0,
                0.0,  1.0,
                1.0,  0.0,
                1.0,  1.0]), 
            this.gl.STATIC_DRAW);
        
        //create texture
        var texture = this.gl.createTexture();
        this.gl.bindTexture(this.gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        
        //normalize image to powers of two
        this.gl.texParameteri(this.gl.TEXTURE_2D, this.gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, this.gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        this.gl.texParameteri(this.gl.TEXTURE_2D, this.gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, this.gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        this.gl.texParameteri(this.gl.TEXTURE_2D, this.gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, this.gl.NEAREST);
        this.gl.texParameteri(this.gl.TEXTURE_2D, this.gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, this.gl.NEAREST);
        
        //load texture from 2d canvas
        this.gl.texImage2D(this.gl.TEXTURE_2D, 
                           0, 
                           this.gl.RGBA, 
                           this.gl.RGBA, 
                           this.gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
                           bufferCanvas);

        //load buffer
        var buffer = this.gl.createBuffer();
        this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
        this.gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this.positionLocation);
        this.gl.vertexAttribPointer(this.positionLocation, 2, this.gl.FLOAT, false, 12, 0);
 
        //draw size and position
        this.gl.bufferData(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([   
            x, y,
            x + bufferCanvas.width, y,
            x, y + bufferCanvas.height,
            x, y + bufferCanvas.height,
            x+ bufferCanvas.width, y,
            x+ bufferCanvas.width, y + bufferCanvas.height]), this.gl.STATIC_DRAW);
        
        //blur width
        this.gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this.width);
        this.gl.vertexAttribPointer(this.width, 1, this.gl.FLOAT, false, 12, 8);
        
        //draw
        this.gl.drawArrays(this.gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
    };
};


var canvas2d = document.getElementById('buffer-canvas');
var context2d = canvas2d.getContext("2d");
var canvasGL = new GL(document.getElementById('main-canvas'));
canvasGL.width = 5.0;

for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    context2d.fillStyle = "rgba(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + "," + a + ")";
    
    var x = Math.random() * canvas2d.width;
    var y = Math.random() * canvas2d.height;
    var width = canvas2d.width - (Math.random() * canvas2d.width);
    var height = canvas2d.height - (Math.random() * canvas2d.height);
    context2d.fillRect(x, y, width , height);
    
    canvasGL.render(canvas2d, canvas2d.getBoundingClientRect("left"), canvas2d.getBoundingClientRect("top"));
}
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sylvester/0.1.3/sylvester.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/mdn/webgl-examples/blob/gh-pages/tutorial/glUtils.js"></script>
  
<script id="vshader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
precision mediump float;

attribute vec2 position;
attribute vec2 texcoord;

uniform vec2 resolution;
uniform float width;

varying vec2 texcoord11;
varying vec2 texcoord00;
varying vec2 texcoord02;
varying vec2 texcoord20;
varying vec2 texcoord22;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(((position / resolution) * 2.0 - 1.0) * vec2(1, -1), 0, 1);

 // get texcoords
 texcoord11 = texcoord;
 texcoord00 = texcoord + vec2(-width, -width);
 texcoord02 = texcoord + vec2( width, -width);
 texcoord20 = texcoord + vec2( width,  width);
 texcoord22 = texcoord + vec2(-width,  width);
}
</script>
  
<script id="fshader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;

uniform sampler2D image;

varying vec2 texcoord11;
varying vec2 texcoord00;
varying vec2 texcoord02;
varying vec2 texcoord20;
varying vec2 texcoord22;

void main()
{
 vec4 blur;
 
 blur = texture2D(image, texcoord11);
 blur += texture2D(image, texcoord00);
 blur += texture2D(image, texcoord02);
 blur += texture2D(image, texcoord20);
 blur += texture2D(image, texcoord22);

 gl_FragColor = 0.2 * blur;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<canvas id="main-canvas" width="400" height="300" style="border:1px solid black;"></canvas>
<canvas id="buffer-canvas" width="400" height="300" style="visibility:hidden;"></canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: The attached code sample generates "Uncaught ReferenceError: gl is not defined" in the first line of the render function, which doesn't seem to be the problem that you are looking to get help with.

Comment: Ah, the clear value. I updated that part, thanks.  *Not* the problem I'm looking for help with. Thanks for recognizing a syntax error can be just that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's several issues with the code

- neither of the script tags seem to be needed
- You assign `this.width` to a uniform location

  ```
  this.width = this.gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "width");
  ```

  But then later destroy that with

  ```
  canvasGL.width = 5.0
  ```
- `width` is a uniform but you're trying to set it as an attribute

  wrong

  ```
  this.gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this.width);
  this.gl.vertexAttribPointer(this.width, 1, this.gl.FLOAT, false, 12, 8);
  ```

  right

  ```
  this.gl.uniform1f(this.width, whateverYouWantedWidthToBe);
  ```
- You've got unneeded strides on all your attributes

  wrong

  ```
  this.gl.vertexAttribPointer(this.texCoordLocation, 2, this.gl.FLOAT, false, 8, 0);
  this.gl.vertexAttribPointer(this.positionLocation, 2, this.gl.FLOAT, false, 12, 0);
  ```

  right

  ```
  this.gl.vertexAttribPointer(this.texCoordLocation, 2, this.gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
  this.gl.vertexAttribPointer(this.positionLocation, 2, this.gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
  ```

  Well I suppose the texcoord one is not *wrong* if you want to set strides but the position one is wrong since you're using 2 floats per position not 3. Why not just set them to 0?
- You're assigning the `texCoordLocation` to a `var` but then using it as a property on `this`

  wrong

  ```
  var texCoordBuffer = this.gl.createBuffer();
  this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.texCoordBuffer);
  ```

  right?

  ```
  this.texCoordBuffer = this.gl.createBuffer();
  this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.texCoordBuffer);
  ```
- On top of that the structure of the code is probably not what you intended.

  In WebGL you don't generally call `gl.createXXX` functions in your render function. You'd call `gl.createXXX` functions those during initialization. [See here for a more typical structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13009328/drawing-many-shapes-in-webgl).
- It's not clear at all what this line is trying to do

  ```
  canvasGL.render(canvas2d, canvas2d.getBoundingClientRect("left"),     
                  canvas2d.getBoundingClientRect("top"))
  ```

  What do you think `canvas2d.getBoundingClientRect()` is going to return that's useful for rendering? Also that's not how `getBoundingClientRect` works. [It returns a rect, it doesn't take any arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect).

Once you have all that fixed it's not clear what you want `width` to be. I'm assuming you want it to be pixels but in that case it needs to be `1 / canvas2D.width` and you need a separate value for `height` in your shader since you'll need different values to move up and down a certain number of pixels vs left and right.

#### other suggestions

- Pull `gl` into a local variable. Then you don't have to do `this.gl` everywhere. Less typing, shorter, and faster
- You can get the contents of script tag with just this

  ```
  var theSource = shaderScript.text;
  ```
- You're checking for shader compile errors but not link errors.
- [`visibility: hidden;` doesn't do what I think you think it does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone). You probably want `display: none;`.

Here's one version that does something.

```js
class GL {
    constructor(canvas){
        var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl") || canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
        if (!gl) {
            alert("Unable to initialize WebGL. Your browser may not support it.");
            return;  
        }
        this.gl = gl;
 
        //init shaders
        var fragmentShader = getShader(gl, "fshader");
        var vertexShader = getShader(gl, "vshader");
        var shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
        gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
        gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
        gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);
        if (!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
            alert("An error occurred linking the shaders: " + gl.getProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram));
            return;
        }
        
      
        this.shaderProgram = shaderProgram;
        
        this.positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "position");
        this.texCoordLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "texcoord");
        this.resolutionLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "resolution");
        this.blurOffsetLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "blurOffset");
    
        // init texture coordinates
        this.texCoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.texCoordBuffer);        
        gl.bufferData(
            gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 
            new Float32Array([
                0.0,  0.0,
                1.0,  0.0,
                0.0,  1.0,
                0.0,  1.0,
                1.0,  0.0,
                1.0,  1.0]), 
            gl.STATIC_DRAW);
        
      
        // create position buffer
        this.positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.positionBuffer);
      
        //create texture
        this.texture = gl.createTexture();
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, this.texture);
        
        //normalize image to powers of two
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
        
        function getShader(gl, id) {
            var shaderScript, theSource, currentChild, shader;
            shaderScript = document.getElementById(id);

            if (!shaderScript) {
                return null;
            }

            var theSource = shaderScript.text;
            
            if (shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-fragment") {
                shader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
            } else if (shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-vertex") {
                shader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
            } else {
                // Unknown shader type
                return null;
            }

            gl.shaderSource(shader, theSource);
            gl.compileShader(shader);

            if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
                alert("An error occurred compiling the shaders: " + gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
                return null;
            }

                return shader;
        };
    };
    
    render(bufferCanvas, x, y, blurAmount) {
        var gl = this.gl;
        gl.clear(this.gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
      
        gl.useProgram(this.shaderProgram);

        // setup buffers and attributes
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.texCoordBuffer);        
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this.texCoordLocation);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(this.texCoordLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
      
        //load buffer
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.positionBuffer);
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this.positionLocation);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(this.positionLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
 
        //draw size and position
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([   
            x, y,
            x + bufferCanvas.width, y,
            x, y + bufferCanvas.height,
            x, y + bufferCanvas.height,
            x+ bufferCanvas.width, y,
            x+ bufferCanvas.width, y + bufferCanvas.height]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
              
        //load texture from 2d canvas
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, this.texture);
        gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 
                      0, 
                      gl.RGBA, 
                      gl.RGBA, 
                      gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
                      bufferCanvas);

        //blur width
        gl.uniform2f(this.blurOffsetLocation, 
                     blurAmount / bufferCanvas.width,
                     blurAmount / bufferCanvas.height);
      
        //set resolution
        gl.uniform2f(this.resolutionLocation, 
                     gl.canvas.width, 
                     gl.canvas.height);     
      
        //draw
        gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
    };
};


var canvas2d = document.getElementById('buffer-canvas');
var context2d = canvas2d.getContext("2d");
var canvasGL = new GL(document.getElementById('main-canvas'));

function render(time) {
    time *= 0.001;
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    context2d.fillStyle = "rgba(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + "," + a + ")";
    
    var x = Math.random() * canvas2d.width;
    var y = Math.random() * canvas2d.height;
    var width = canvas2d.width - (Math.random() * canvas2d.width);
    var height = canvas2d.height - (Math.random() * canvas2d.height);
    context2d.fillRect(x, y, width , height);
    canvasGL.render(canvas2d, 0, 0, Math.sin(time) * 5);
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```html
<script id="vshader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
precision mediump float;

attribute vec2 position;
attribute vec2 texcoord;

uniform vec2 resolution;
uniform vec2 blurOffset;

varying vec2 texcoord11;
varying vec2 texcoord00;
varying vec2 texcoord02;
varying vec2 texcoord20;
varying vec2 texcoord22;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(((position / resolution) * 2.0 - 1.0) * vec2(1, -1), 0, 1);

 // get texcoords
 texcoord11 = texcoord;
 texcoord00 = texcoord + blurOffset * vec2(-1, -1);
 texcoord02 = texcoord + blurOffset * vec2( 1, -1);
 texcoord20 = texcoord + blurOffset * vec2( 1,  1);
 texcoord22 = texcoord + blurOffset * vec2(-1,  1);
}
</script>
  
<script id="fshader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;

uniform sampler2D image;

varying vec2 texcoord11;
varying vec2 texcoord00;
varying vec2 texcoord02;
varying vec2 texcoord20;
varying vec2 texcoord22;

void main()
{
 vec4 blur;
 
 blur = texture2D(image, texcoord11);
 blur += texture2D(image, texcoord00);
 blur += texture2D(image, texcoord02);
 blur += texture2D(image, texcoord20);
 blur += texture2D(image, texcoord22);

    // do you really want to blend the alpha?
 gl_FragColor = 0.2 * blur;
}
</script>

<canvas id="main-canvas" width="400" height="300" style="border:1px solid black;"></canvas>
<canvas id="buffer-canvas" width="400" height="300" style="display: none;"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I want to petition Mozilla to pay you to write WebGL tuts :) A few notes and follow-ups: First of all, "width" here is just dimensions of surrounding pixels used for convolution: nothing to do with buffer dimensions. Also, the 2nd & 3rd args to gl.render (should have been `getgetBoundingClientRect().left`, etc.) are intended to set texture position inside the larger gl canvas (for example when compositing multiple buffers). Here they're both 0, but it does appear to work in more complex examples.

Comment: As far as whether I want to blend the alpha channels...this will only be convoluting pixels with frames from the same image, therefore unless I use it for some pretty serious live compositing the alpha channel should be the same for all pixels. I've never had them be an issue with convolution effects before, but maybe I should consider stripping them out first?

Comment: Finally, something I've been wondering for a while: I know you never set stride with a buffer of just one attribute, but others have referred to my code as sloppy for doing so. Any thoughts on this? Is it just an inane style debate? If memory serves me I've seen you refer to it as actually *increasing* GPU load, but I don't see how that could be. Anyway, you're correct I made an odd error in computing one of them so that's clearly a reason to avoid it...

Comment: I'm actually not an image processing expert by any means so I don't know what to do with alpha. I'd have to look it up. As for `canvas2d.getBoundingClientRect().left` it's still not clear what you're trying to do. All that returns is the left position *on the webpage* of your invisible canvas that never moves. It's not apparent how that would be relevant to anything you're trying to do. It gives you no info about what's in the canvas or anything you drew in the canvas.

Comment: Imagine I want my gl canvas divided into three buffers all precisely positioned: that's what I'd use those params for. However, I haven't tested this loop yet that way. I think I'll likely have to move where I call gl.clear so it doesn't overwrite the previous ones until I've drawn the frames from the rest. I'll comment here with a link later today or tomorrow just so you can see what I'm trying to say.

Comment: Okay, compare [a very slow yet beautiful CPU-based approximation of Gaussian blur](http://sretaeper.ucoz.com/stalker_blur/index.html) with [the same using this blur shader](http://sretaeper.ucoz.com/convolution/blur.html). Please note these use both React.js and [a tiny sprite animation of my own.](https://github.com/Sophia-Gold/spriteAnimation.js) Obviously I'd need to use at least two FBOs to get anything close to a satisfactory blur in WebGL. But for now I'm not trying for that: just playing around with various convolution methods and appreciate you providing me with a solid basis to start.