# Is there a way to have two images on a cube?

Tags: javascript, webgl

I'm trying to have two external images as textures for my cube. When I use one image, it works perfectly and my cube is rendered but I'm having problems rendering two images on one cube. One is a spotlight image that has the middle cut out so the second image placed can be seen through that hole. The only warning I get is

WebGL warning: generateMipmap: Tex image TEXTURE_2D level 0 is incurring lazy initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I try to run your code in Chrome 80 I get error messages in the [JavaScript console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/javascript)

The first one is this

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on 'WebGLRenderingContext': parameter 9 is not of type 'ArrayBufferView'.
>       at configureTexture1 (js:148)

You're trying to pass an `HTMLImageElement` to `texImage2D` but the only form of `texImage2D` that takes an `HTMLImageElement` has 6 parameters, not 9. No width, no height, and no border parameter.  It should be

```
gl.texImage2D(
   gl.TEXTURE_2D,
   0,                // level
   gl.RGBA,          // internal format
   gl.RGBA,          // format
   gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, // type
   someImageElement);
```

Fixing those 2 errors leads to a new error

> WARNING: there is no texture bound to the unit 1

When you use multiple textures you need to assign each texture to a texture unit. Example

```
// bind "someTexture" to texture unit 0
gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0 + 0);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, someTexture);

// bind "otherTexture" to texture unit 1
gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0 + 1);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, otherTexture);
```

```js
var canvas;
var gl;

var numVertices  = 36;
var texSize = 64;

var image1 = document.getElementById("texImage1");
var image2 = document.getElementById("texImage2");

var program;

var texture1, texture2;

var pointsArray = [];
var colorsArray = [];
var texCoordsArray = [];


//texture coordinates
var texCoord = [
    vec2(0, 0),
    vec2(0, 1),
    vec2(1, 1),
    vec2(1, 0)
];

//cube dimensions
var vertices = [
    vec4( -0.5, -0.5,  0.5, 1.0 ),
    vec4( -0.5,  0.5,  0.5, 1.0 ),
    vec4( 0.5,  0.5,  0.5, 1.0 ),
    vec4( 0.5, -0.5,  0.5, 1.0 ),
    vec4( -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 1.0 ),
    vec4( -0.5,  0.5, -0.5, 1.0 ),
    vec4( 0.5,  0.5, -0.5, 1.0 ),
    vec4( 0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 1.0 )
];

var vertexColors = [
    vec4( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  
    vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  
    vec4( 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  
    vec4( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  
    vec4( 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 ),  
    vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 ),  
    vec4( 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 ),  
    vec4( 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 )   
];

//rotation parameters
var xAxis = 0;
var yAxis = 1;
var zAxis = 2;
var axis = xAxis;

var theta = [45.0, 45.0, 45.0];

var thetaLoc;

function configureTexture1( image ) {
    texture1 = gl.createTexture();
    gl.activeTexture( gl.TEXTURE0 + 0 );
    gl.bindTexture( gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture1 );
    gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image1);
    gl.generateMipmap( gl.TEXTURE_2D );
    gl.texParameteri( gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,gl.NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR );
    gl.texParameteri( gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);

    gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation( program, "texture1"), 0);
}


function configureTexture2( image ) {
    texture2 = gl.createTexture();
    gl.activeTexture( gl.TEXTURE0 + 1 );
    gl.bindTexture( gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture2 );
    gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image2);
    gl.generateMipmap( gl.TEXTURE_2D );
    gl.texParameteri( gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,gl.NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR );
    gl.texParameteri( gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);

    gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation( program, "texture2"), 1);
}

function quad(a, b, c, d) {
     pointsArray.push(vertices[a]);
     colorsArray.push(vertexColors[a]);
     texCoordsArray.push(texCoord[0]);

     pointsArray.push(vertices[b]);
     colorsArray.push(vertexColors[a]);
     texCoordsArray.push(texCoord[1]);

     pointsArray.push(vertices[c]);
     colorsArray.push(vertexColors[a]);
     texCoordsArray.push(texCoord[2]);

     pointsArray.push(vertices[a]);
     colorsArray.push(vertexColors[a]);
     texCoordsArray.push(texCoord[0]);

     pointsArray.push(vertices[c]);
     colorsArray.push(vertexColors[a]);
     texCoordsArray.push(texCoord[2]);

     pointsArray.push(vertices[d]);
     colorsArray.push(vertexColors[a]);
     texCoordsArray.push(texCoord[3]);
}

function colorCube()
{
    quad( 1, 0, 3, 2 );
    quad( 2, 3, 7, 6 );
    quad( 3, 0, 4, 7 );
    quad( 6, 5, 1, 2 );
    quad( 4, 5, 6, 7 );
    quad( 5, 4, 0, 1 );
}


window.onload = function init() {

    canvas = document.getElementById( "gl-canvas" );

    gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL( canvas );
    if ( !gl ) { alert( "WebGL isn't available" ); }

    gl.viewport( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
    gl.clearColor( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );

    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

    program = initShaders( gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader" );
    gl.useProgram( program );

    colorCube();


    //loading/initialising/binding buffers
    var cBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBuffer );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(colorsArray), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

    var vColor = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vColor" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vColor, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vColor );

    var vBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer);
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(pointsArray), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

    var vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vPosition" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vPosition, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vPosition );

    var tBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, tBuffer);
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(texCoordsArray), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

    var vTexCoord = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vTexCoord" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vTexCoord, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vTexCoord );

    configureTexture1(image1);
    configureTexture2(image2);

    thetaLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "theta");


 document.getElementById("ButtonX").onclick = function(){axis = xAxis;};
 document.getElementById("ButtonY").onclick = function(){axis = yAxis;};
 document.getElementById("ButtonZ").onclick = function(){axis = zAxis;};

    render();
}

var render = function() {
    gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    theta[axis] += 2.0;
    gl.uniform3fv(thetaLoc, flatten(theta));
        
    gl.drawArrays( gl.TRIANGLES, 0, numVertices );
    requestAnimFrame(render);
}
```

```html
<button id = "ButtonX">Rotate X</button>
<button id = "ButtonY">Rotate Y</button>
<button id = "ButtonZ">Rotate Z</button>

<script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">

attribute  vec4 vPosition;
attribute  vec4 vColor;
attribute  vec2 vTexCoord;

varying vec4 fColor;
varying vec2 fTexCoord;

uniform vec3 theta;

void main()
{

    vec3 angles = radians( theta );
    vec3 c = cos( angles );
    vec3 s = sin( angles );

    mat4 rx = mat4( 1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0,
            0.0,  c.x,  s.x, 0.0,
            0.0, -s.x,  c.x, 0.0,
            0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0 );

    mat4 ry = mat4( c.y, 0.0, -s.y, 0.0,
            0.0, 1.0,  0.0, 0.0,
            s.y, 0.0,  c.y, 0.0,
            0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 1.0 );


    mat4 rz = mat4( c.z, s.z, 0.0, 0.0,
            -s.z,  c.z, 0.0, 0.0,
            0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
            0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );

    fColor = vColor;
    fTexCoord = vTexCoord;
    gl_Position = rz * ry * rx * vPosition;

}
</script>

<script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">

precision mediump float;

varying vec4 fColor;
varying  vec2 fTexCoord;

uniform sampler2D texture1;
uniform sampler2D texture2;

void
main()
{
    gl_FragColor = fColor*(texture2D(texture1, fTexCoord)*texture2D(texture2, fTexCoord));

}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"
src="https://esangel.github.io/WebGL/Common/webgl-utils.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://esangel.github.io/WebGL/Common/initShaders.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="https://esangel.github.io/WebGL/Common/MV.js"></script>

<canvas id="gl-canvas" width="512" height="512">
Oops ... your browser doesn't support the HTML5 canvas element
</canvas>
<img id="texImage1" crossorigin=" " src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbEMh.png" crossOrigin="anonymous" hidden></img>
<img id="texImage2" crossorigin=" " src = "https://i.imgur.com/aqZRuFj.png" crossOrigin="anonymous" hidden></img>
```

I used these 2 images

An F: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbEMh.png

A white dot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNMqc.jpg

note that the code is not following normal WebGL practices. Many things are being done once at init time which will only work as long as you're onyl drawing a single thing.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20850791/128511) and/or [this page](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-drawing-multiple-things.html) and [this one too](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-texture-units.html)

Comment: i tried editing the code as you mentioned sir, however I get an error WebGLRenderingContext.texImage2D: Argument 6 is not valid for any of the 6-argument overloads.

Comment: The code in the answer is working and is the code you posted in your question with only the 2 changes mentioned so maybe compare what's in it to what you have on your machine though you'll need to remove the `crossOrigin="anonymous"` attributes from the images. Those are needed to load images from a different website than the page itself is running on

Comment: @mathgeek, you can scroll down [here](http://www.mergely.com/aRyER7qz/) and see the only differences between your code and the working code are in `configureTexture1` and `configureTexture2`

Comment: Also you might find [this](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/resources/webgl-state-diagram.html) helpful in understanding WebGL

Comment: thank you for all the references! i'll make sure to check them to get more understanding. i have images saved in the same file as my js and html file but it still seems to give me an error regardless of the browser. I shall go through the links you've given to fix them

Comment: Does the example in the answer above run for you?

Comment: yes when i run the code snippet i can see the F cube rotating